# How to use predict.gam in mgcv package to calculate first derivative

Tags: r, derivative, gam, mgcv

In "predict.gam Prediction from fitted GAM model" documentation, I've found the example code to calculate the derivatives of smooths. But I cannot understand how it works, then in my dataset, it goes wrong. I fitted my 1D dataset with p-splines in mgcv and the gam() model is mgcv.ps now when I was trying to plot the first derivative following the instruction of example code, it didn't work like example did.

The example code is as follows:
    ####################################################################
        ## Differentiating the smooths in a model (with CIs for   derivatives)
            ####################################################################

```
## simulate data and fit model...
dat <- gamSim(1,n=300,scale=sig)
b<-gam(y~s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat)
plot(b,pages=1)
## now evaluate derivatives of smooths with associated standard
## errors, by finite differencing...
x.mesh <- seq(0,1,length=200) ## where to evaluate derivatives
newd <- data.frame(x0 = x.mesh,x1 = x.mesh, x2=x.mesh,x3=x.mesh)
X0 <- predict(b,newd,type="lpmatrix")
eps <- 1e-7 ## finite difference interval
x.mesh <- x.mesh + eps ## shift the evaluation mesh
newd <- data.frame(x0 = x.mesh,x1 = x.mesh, x2=x.mesh,x3=x.mesh)
X1 <- predict(b,newd,type="lpmatrix")
Xp <- (X1-X0)/eps ## maps coefficients to (fd approx.) derivatives
colnames(Xp)      ## can check which cols relate to which smooth
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
for (i in 1:4) {  ## plot derivatives and corresponding CIs
  Xi <- Xp*0
  Xi[,(i-1)*9+1:9+1] <- Xp[,(i-1)*9+1:9+1] ## Xi%*%coef(b) = smooth     deriv i
  df <- Xi%*%coef(b)              ## ith smooth derivative
  df.sd <- rowSums(Xi%*%b$Vp*Xi)^.5 ## cheap diag(Xi%*%b$Vp%*%t(Xi))^.5
  plot(x.mesh,df,type="l",ylim=range(c(df+2*df.sd,df-2*df.sd)))
  lines(x.mesh,df+2*df.sd,lty=2);lines(x.mesh,df-2*df.sd,lty=2)
}
```

In my dataset, cause the x-axis is from 1 to 55(55 months in total), so I let the x.mesh to be #x.mesh<- seq(0,54,length = 55). Then follow the example code, but what're the #esp# mean? I think it means the t-(t-1), so I give the #esp = 1#. However, I do not quite understand what #forloop# in the example does. I think because of the 4 x variables in the example. It uses for (i in 1 to 4), however, I only have 1 x variable, so the following plotting I ran the mistake happened. Could someone explain detailed information in the last function of example code? And what I should do with the code to meet my fitted model.

My fitted model is as follows:

```
dataset <- read.csv("bsplinesforR.csv", header = TRUE)

x <- dataset[,2]
y <- dataset[,4]
## define plotting parameters
vdist <- hdist <- 0.2
layout(matrix(1:4, 2, 2, byrow=TRUE), widths= c(10, 10), heights= c(10, 10))
par(mar= c(vdist, 4, 3, hdist))
plot(x, y, ylab="y", xlab="", axes=FALSE)
axis(2); axis(3); box()

library(mgcv)
mgcv.ps <- gam(y~s(x,bs="ps"), method = "REML")

t.g <- predict(mgcv.ps)

lines(x, t.gl,col=2, lwd=2)
lines(x, t.g,col=3, lwd=2)
legend(5, 600, c("Real", "gamlss", "mgcv"), col=c(1, 2, 3), lty=c(2, 1, 1), bty="n")
layout(matrix(1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: The loop is iterating over the smooth terms of the model. If you look at `head(Xp)`, there are 9 segments for each term, so `Xp[, (i-1)*9 + 1:9 + 1]` is extracting part of `Xp` for each term. So if you just have 1 smooth, you just need to ignore the intercept column (the first one) and you can skip the loop.

Comment: Hi @alistaire, if I just skip the loop, it would give me the error "Error in Xp[, (i - 1) * 9 + 1:9 + 1]: subscript out of bounds"

Comment: Right, you need to look at `Xp` and figure out what indices you need. If you've got the same number of knots, it would be columns `2:10`.

Comment: HI @alistaire, that was amazing! Thanks so so much! May I ask for why both 4 smooths and 1 smooth do not need to consider the intercept column? In what situation, we need to take them? Honestly, I am new to p-splines, so could you tell me in Xp, the 2-10 columns (s(x).1...s(x).9) stand for what? Do they stand for knots?

Comment: And in my understanding, the first derivative is calculating by the 55 difference of y values divided by difference of time. If in my next item, the knots increases to 13, so that it means I need to take the 2-14 columns?